# How to use socket.io in a browser?

Tags: javascript, sockets, browser, socket.io, client

I'm trying to use socket.io for the browser. The problem is that I have no idea how to get it.
I'm following this tutorial (http://buildnewgames.com/real-time-multiplayer/) and there, they use `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`. The problem is that this file doesn't exist and on the webiste of sockeit.io, there's no download for it.

Comment: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/tree/master/dist

Comment: use cdn: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js